# Расположение файла для параметра AuthUserFile

Tags: apache

Доброго времени суток!
Я пытаюсь настроить аутентификацию **Apache**, используя для начала **Basic**. В моем распоряжении есть **shared** хостинг, на котором я не могу управлять настройками веб-сервера. Я подготовил на "домашнем" веб-сервере Apache (работает под Windows) файлик идентификатор:пароль и положил его в ту же директорию, которую хочу защитить от доступа с использованием **.htaccess**. Я знаю, что мануал по **Apache** категорически не рекомендует именно так поступать, но тем не менее этот вариант пока что мне подходит. 
"Исследования" показали, что файлик с паролем ищется именно в "домашней" директории **Apache**, куда на хостинге мне доступа нет. Поэтому хочу спросить, как прописать параметр **AuthUserFile file.txt** так, чтобы **file.txt** брался именно из текущей директории?

---

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin area"
AuthUserFile d:\web\htdocs\test\file.txt
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых файл с паролями ищется не в домашнем каталоге Apache, а, при относительном пути, как путь, относительно директивы `ServerRoot`.

Во-вторых - в директиве **AuthUserFile** вам нужно указать абсолютный путь к файлу `file.txt`. В вашем случае, если нужный файл лежит в каталоге admin, то полный путь будет завершаться на `public_html/admin/file.txt`. А вот что там в начале будет - вам нужно уточнить у тех. поддержки вашего хостинга. Скажите им, что вам нужно узнать полный путь к файлу - они подскажут. Или, если у вас есть SSH доступ к хостингу, подключитесь и выполните команду `pwd` - она напишет полный путь к *текущему* каталогу. От него уже постройте путь к нужному вам файлу.

Comment: To @МАН69К Спасибо, есть сдвиги, но 1) Выдает ошибку _AH01630: client denied by server configuration_. Гугление и добавление **Require all granted** не помогает. Содержимое каталога браузер видит.  (( 2) Как прописать расположение файла на хостинге, если, предположим, каталог для файлов public_html и в нем есть папка admin

Comment: @Apron63: по первой ошибке - дополните ваш первоначальный вопрос содержимым файла .htaccess. По поводу каталога - дополнил свой ответ.